# Can spring.messages.basename be an IP Address

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, httpurlconnection

The `spring.messages.basename` is set to an IP address like:

```
spring:
  messages:
    basename: http://1.2.3.4:8888/messages.properties
```

That is the IP of a spring cloud config server.
When the app starts up, it's trying to send a request to that url but with all dots being replaced by slashes:

```
s.n.www.protocol.http.httpurlconnection  : ProxySelector Request for http://1/2/3/4:8888/messages.properties
```

As the IP address is messed up, the connection hangs and the app could not start up properly.

Debugging into the source code, this method `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.context.MessageSourceAutoConfiguration.ResourceBundleCondition#getResources` is found being responsible for the corrupted IP.

[image: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.context.MessageSourceAutoConfiguration.ResourceBundleCondition#getResources]

Additionally, there is already a messageSource bean in the app configuration like:

```
@Bean(name = "messageSource")
public MessageSource messageSource(@Value("${spring.messages.basename:}") String basename) {
 ...
}
```

Hence, when configuring a timeout for that malformed URL request, the app can still start up successfully and with the proper message loaded.

So the questions are:

1. Why is the `MessageSourceAutoConfiguration` trying to send a request for resources supposed to be in the classpath (That method is trying to get resources from classpath)?
2. Should the `MessageSourceAutoConfiguration` load the message resource when there is already a bean created for that?
3. How to disable the MessageSourceAutoConfiguration or get rid of the malformed IP request without having to put a timeout for it?
4. Is it valid to set `spring.messages.basename`to an IP Address?

`spring-boot` version: 2.6.6
`spring` version: 5.3.18

Answer (score 3):

You cannot specify a URL for `spring.messages.basename`.  See [this page](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.13.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-internationalization.html) where it says:

> `spring.messages.basename` supports comma-separated list of locations, either a package qualifier or a resource resolved from the classpath root.

It is a resource name pointing to a file inside the classpath, not a URL.